# webpack and knockoutjs without "externals"?

Tags: knockout.js, webpack

Is it possible to use knockoutjs together with webpack? Right now, I just have the following in my html

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

together with an entry in the webpack config like so

```
externals: {
    'ko': 'ko'
}
```

I would instead like to use whatever version of ko I have installed with `yarn`.

It seems to be related this [this line](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/commit/847e1f199eb2057b40a2c7938b4df332450302f9#diff-f8448cf32a150a19b9571ae6d74982f8R6) in knockoutjs, and there seems to be some kind of hint for a work-around for this [over here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/424#issuecomment-53241714).

Ideally, I would like to still use a script tag (injected by webpack into the html), but that I think I can figure out myself if only knockout could be loaded from `node_modules` somehow...

How do I `require` knockout installed with yarn without the `externals` entry in my webpack config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huge success. Following the link in the question I managed to get it rolling with the following entry in the webpack config

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /knockout.build.output.knockout-latest\.js/,
      loader: "imports?require=>false"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then I can just `require('knockout')`

Comment: it is confusing. I put knockout into module.exports.entry section and it is working for with require('knockout'). No loaders needed. Can you explain why this did not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get knockout to work with webpack.
My project was well underway when I added knockout.

npm i knockout --save

In webpack.config.js in the module.exports plugins I used:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      Util: 'exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util',
      ko: 'exports-loader?!knockout'
    })
```

Then I was able to import knockout in my entry file:

```
import './index.scss';
import 'bootstrap/js/src/tab';
import 'bootstrap/js/src/modal';
import 'knockout';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution. You can use [IgnorePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/).

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = [
    {
        entry: {
            "knockout": [
             // Inside file below there is 'require("knockout")' 
             // invocation which webpack cannot resolve.
             // We need to tell webpack to not to resolve that
             // and leave 'require("knockout")' whithout any changes.
             // By that this code will be resolved on runtime
             // which means that we need to attach script to 
             // knockout somewhere in project. 
             "./js/knockout/knockout.mapping-latest.js",
            ]
        },
        output: {
            filename: "./dist/[name].js"
        },
        plugins: [
            // This tells to webpack: if you'll find 
            // somewhere in code 'require("knockout")'
            // don't try to resolve that. Leave it as is. 
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^knockout$/),
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Why is the IgnorePlugin needed?

Answer (score -1):

Put knockout into module.exports.entry section and it is working. All you need is to include it into your js file like so require('knockout').

> webpack.config.js

```
module.exports.entry = {
    vendor: [
        'jquery',
        'knockout',
        'bootstrap'            
    ],
    emal_patient_form : [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/EmalPatientForm.js')
    ]
};
...
```

> ... /resources/js/EmalPatientForm.js

```
...
const ko = require("knockout");
const myViewModel = {
     error_messsage: ko.observable(''),
     alert: ko.observable('')
 };
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
...
```

Comment: example is added.

Comment: does not work for me. I tried in new project, by doing `yarn add knockout`

Comment: I'm using NPM. Do you have any error messages? How do you know it is not working for you? What is your webpack.config.js?